What can we learn from غسل from Quran only?
Quran commands us to تغتسلوا (wash yourself). If we don't consider Hadith (and sects), what can we learn only from the Quran?

To wash your body. By default it would mean wash your entire body. That leaves questions like whether the inside of one's mouth, nose and throat is included, whether intention matters, whether washing includes rubbing or just pouring water, whether taking a break to do something else makes any difference.

Somewhat related is the discussion of verse 5:6 in quran originally without vowels marks.

@UmH, can you provide more details on why the word "ghusl" by default means washing the entire body? I saw the link you provided and I did not see references for this.
